# PHP dynamically create multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I need to dynamically compute my multidimensional array keys  for an aggegration in Elasticsearch.

I have the following

`$aggs['aggs']['name']`

But aggs and name needs to be populated in a loop. So for example:

```
 $aggs['aggs']['name']['aggs']  = $glue;

// looping

$aggs['aggs']['name']['aggs']['name']['aggs'] = $glue;

// looping

 $aggs['aggs']['name']['aggs']['name']['aggs']['name']['aggs']  = $glue;

// etc
```

The array keys needs to be computed with the keys `aggs` and `name`

How can i dynamically create keys in an array?

Thanks

Comment: 1st iteration adds just `aggs`? and from 2nd adds `[name][aggs]`?

Comment: have a snippet? Because i cannot add the brackets, they needs to be populated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope this is what you want. I have created one array with keys. Then traverse that array to create multi dimension array

```
$keys = array("aggs","name","aggs","name","aggs");
$aggs = array();

$aggs = add_keys_dynamic($aggs,$keys,"test");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($aggs);

function add_keys_dynamic($main_array, $keys, $value){    
    $tmp_array = &$main_array;
    while( count($keys) > 0 ){        
        $k = array_shift($keys);        
        if(!is_array($tmp_array)){
            $tmp_array = array();
        }
        $tmp_array = &$tmp_array[$k];
    }
    $tmp_array = $value;
    return $main_array;
}
```

**[Example](https://eval.in/828697)**

Comment: Quick and simple. Saved my day, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

use the `array_walk_recursive` function

```
<?php
$aggs['aggs']['name'] = "name";

function addEnd(&$item, $key)
{
    if(is_array($item)){
        return;
    }elseif($key=='aggs'){
        $item=['name'=> ['aggs' => $item]];
    }else{
        $item=['aggs' => $item];
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ // your loop
    array_walk_recursive($aggs, 'addEnd');
}

var_dump($aggs);
```

check it here: https://3v4l.org/HmlYD